# How to align Bootstrap cards when resizing window and make them same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

I'm trying to create 5 elements of same height using bootstrap. Ideally I want it to look like this on different screen sizes.

[image]

I have used Bootstrap's Grid system to achieve this however what I've gotten is something like this:

[image]

What is the good method to make these elements the same height and align them properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="stack.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">  
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="card">
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="">
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-block">

        <h4 class="card-title">Some Title</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Lorem </p>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="button" > 
            <a href="" target="_blank">Button</a>
        </div>

        </div> <!--/.Card content-->
    </div> <!--/.Card-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box ">  
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="card">
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="">
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-block">

        <h4 class="card-title">Some Title</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco lin voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="button" > 
            <a href="" target="_blank">Button</a>
        </div>

        </div> <!--/.Card content-->
    </div> <!--/.Card-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">  
    <div>3</div>
    <div class="card">
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="">
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-block">

        <h4 class="card-title">Some Title</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.si ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="button" > 
            <a href="" target="_blank">Button</a>
        </div>

        </div> <!--/.Card content-->
    </div> <!--/.Card-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">  
    <div>4</div>
    <div class="card">
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="">
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-block">

        <h4 class="card-title">Some Title</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehen</p>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="button" > 
            <a href="" target="_blank">Button</a>
        </div>

        </div> <!--/.Card content-->
    </div> <!--/.Card-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">  
    <div>5</div>
    <div class="card">
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="">
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-block">

        <h4 class="card-title">Some Title</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con</p>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="button" > 
            <a href="" target="_blank">Button</a>
        </div>

        </div> <!--/.Card content-->
    </div> <!--/.Card-->
</div>

 </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `.row` display to `flex`, then just add parameter to it's childs(`.box`) `flex: 1` which's shorthand for `flex-grow` & `flex-shrink`(about this one we does not care). That will make your child components same height.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make everything the same height by adding flex to the class row. However now all five elements are in one line. How do I shift elements to the next row as I resize window?

Comment: `
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.row:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
}

.box:nth-of-type(n + 4) {
  order: 1;
}
`

With this code you can break the line, but there becomes a little thing. Height's restarting to max-height of the new line.